# Elasticsearch - combining query_string and bool query in filter

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, query-string, booleanquery

Is it possible to combine `query_string` and `bool query` in `filter query`?

For Example -

```
{
  "filter": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "field:text"
    }
  },
  "bool": {
    "should": {
      "match": {
        "field": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

bool is meant to be used to club various queries together into a single bool query.
You can use bool to combine multiple queries in this manner -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "field:text"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "field": "text"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The must clause will make sure all the conditions are matched.
You can also use should which will make sure either one of the query is matched in case of only should is used.

As bool is just another query type , you can also club bool queries inside bool queries as follows -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "field:text"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "field": "value"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "field": "text"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can we target multiple fields?

Comment: @OliverDixon "query_string": { "query": "field:text", "fields":['field1","field2"] }